# Office web app error SharePoint 2010

Tags: service-applications

if we try to view word,ppt and excel via browser ..cannnot view, throw error

**Word**

Error alert

Microsoft Word Web AppWord Web App cannot open this document for viewing because of an unexpected error. To view this document, open it in Microsoft Word.

Error Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

**PPt**

PowerPoint Web App cannot open this presentation for viewing because of an unexpected error. To view this presentation, open it in Microsoft PowerPoint

**Excel**

error 1: Workbook cannot opened

error2 : unable to process the request Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again

**Event view error below**

A Word or PowerPoint front end failed to communicate with backend machine 
http://test:3233/4248b98696d04ec7b4b3598658b0c3e9/Conversion.svc

Please assit me for fix this  issue

**Note** : realted services all are working fine

Answer (score 2):

The most common causes of problems with Office Web Applications are:

- OWA not installed (obvious, but it happens)
- Word viewing/PowerPoint/Excel calculation service not started
- Word viewing/PowerPoint/Excel calculation service application not created
- OWA service account does not have db_owner rights on the content database

I would suggest checking through these first.

Comment: yes...i follow •OWA service account does not have db_owner rights on the content database
 its working fine now

Comment: Good. If you are happy that this answers your question, please "accept" it (using the icon in the left margin - only the questioner is able to do this). Apart from rewarding the provider of the answer, this makes it easier for other users of the site.

Comment: A follow up with code examples might help others here `Get-SPWebApplication | % { $_.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity((Get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity "SharePoint Web Services" | select -expand ProcessAccountName)) }` this will add the selected system application pool user as db_owner on all content databases in the web applications, grant user read access to config db, grant the user full control policy to all content in web app and add the user to WSS_WPG local group on all servers in farm.